# unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'Timestamp'

Tags: python, pandas

Statement :

```
 df[df['Symbol'] =="TLT" & df['Date'].max()]
```

> Error : unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'Timestamp'

My pandas dataframe is df. It consists of a trading log.

When I filter the df on Symbol and(&) timestamp I get the above error

What did I do incorrectly ? I don't want to change my timestamp to a str.

df

```
            Date    Symbol
 49     2018-11-27  0
 50     2018-12-10  0
 51     2018-12-17  0
 52     2018-12-27  XLK
 53     2018-12-27  XLV
 54     2018-12-28  VTV
 55     2019-01-09  0
 56     2019-01-09  0
 57     2019-01-16  0
 58     2019-02-04  0
 59     2019-02-04  0
 61     2019-02-05  SPY
 62     2019-02-05  0
 60     2019-02-05  TLT
 63     2019-02-07  TLT
 64     2019-02-09  0
```

Expected results : 63

Actual results : unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'Timestamp'

Comment: df['Date'].max() not a boolean condition , plz check

Comment: When filtering for TLT and XLK , still is empty dataframe. When filtering for SPY and VTV , this gives me data. So it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add parenthesis, because [operator precedence in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). The bitwise and (&) has precedence over equal (==) so in this case the parenthesis are required. Also compare column `Date` with `max`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df[(df['Symbol'] == "TLT") & (df['Date'] == df['Date'].max())]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below to find the result

```
df.loc[(df['Symbol'] == "TLT") & (df['Date'] == df['Date'].max())]
```

here the '&' operator takes precendee over the '=='operator.

Comment: I am not getting an error now with df.loc or df statement but it is returning a blank dataframe with column names.

Comment: What am i doing wrong ? A blank dataframe is not what I wanted