# filtering a pandas dataframe for the max date and symbol

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I asked a question here and I don't get an error but an empty dataframe with columns. What am I doing wrong ?

My original data frame is below

```
               Date    Symbol
     49     2018-11-27  0
     50     2018-12-10  0
     51     2018-12-17  0
     52     2018-12-27  XLK
     53     2018-12-27  XLV
     54     2018-12-28  VTV
     55     2019-01-09  0
     56     2019-01-09  0
     57     2019-01-16  0
     58     2019-02-04  0
     59     2019-02-04  0
     61     2019-02-05  SPY
     62     2019-02-05  0
     60     2019-02-05  TLT
     63     2019-02-07  TLT
     64     2019-02-09  0
```

The statement following statement works but gives me an empty dataframe :

```
df.loc[(df['Symbol'] == "TLT") & (df['Date'] == df['Date'].max())]
```

link 
[unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'Timestamp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54760915/unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-timestamp)

Answer (score 3):

Convert column to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), also `loc` is not necessare, so should be removed:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df[(df['Symbol'] == "TLT") & (df['Date'] == df['Date'].max())]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add some ideas. You can also use `idxmax()` or `idxmin()`

```py
df.loc[df.groupby('Date')['Symbol'].idxmax()]
```

This will give you all maximum `Date` of each `Symbol` categories.

Comment: Good suggestion but doesn't work.    'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute '_aggregate_item_by_item

Comment: @JohnJohn do this first? `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`